# Swift 3 - Structs in a Collection

Tags: swift, struct, collections, hashable

Why doesn't the following code work? And what do I need to change to make it work?

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

struct Person: CustomDebugStringConvertible, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    // MARK: CustomDebugStringConvertible

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "\(name) is \(age) years old"
    }

    // MARK: Hashable

    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.hashValue ^ age.hashValue
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.age == rhs.age
}

let ilse = Person(name: "Ilse", age: 33)
let mark = Person(name: "Mark", age: 38)

extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Person {
    var averageAge: Int {
        let sum = self.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.age }
        let count = self.count as! Int
        return sum / count
    }
}

var people = [Person]()
people.append(ilse)
people.append(mark)

let averageAge = people.averageAge
```

I figured out that if I make the struct a Swift class it works. Does it have something to do with the struct being a value type? I do see a compiler error on the last line. "'[Person]' is not convertible to '<>'"

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Person
```

restricts `Iterator.Element` to types which adopt the *protocol* `Person`
or are a *subclass* of `Person`. Both is not possible with
`struct Person`, and in the full compiler log you'll find

> error: type 'Iterator.Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'Person'

What you probably mean is

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Person
```

which restricts the extension to collections of `Person`.
Alternatively, define a protocol

```
protocol HasAge {
    var age: Int { get }
}
```

adopt that by `Person`

```
struct Person: CustomDebugStringConvertible, Hashable, HasAge { ... }
```

and define the extension for collections of elements which have a age:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: HasAge { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't know there was Iterator.Element == Person even possible.

Comment: @user3654258: Such a "same-type requirement" is possible for `Collection` (which itself a protocol), but currently not for `Array` (which is a generic struct).

Answer (score 1):

Change your Collection's extension to this

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Person {
    var averageAge: Int {
        let sum = self.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.age }
        let count = self.count as! Int
        return sum / count
    }
}
```